hibernate not working in 24.04LTS, but used to work with 20.04Lts
using swapfile method - not swap partition. 24.04LTS seems to be obsessed with something called 'hibernate.target'... asks for password, but nothing happens. been using systemctl hibernate via hotkey on 20.04LTS.

used this to try to get hibernate to work in 24.04LTS:
How to Enable Hibernate Function in Ubuntu 24.04 & 22.04 LTS
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/

"How to Enable Hibernate Function in Ubuntu 24.04 & 22.04 LTS" didn't seem to work - looking at Ubuntu's info on Power Management/Hibernate at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate?_gl=11a5g98b_gcl_au*MTEzNzY5MDI0Ny4xNzE1MTgyMDg1&_ga=2.193245357.1834305209.1715182082-1763103473.1715182082
...but it is such a radically different approach :-\

Upgrade your kernel to 6.9. You can follow this steps to update through a GUI very comfortable. This solved for me

been there and did that - installed 6.9.3 kernel (latest "stable" [sic] kernel) - fails to hibernate and it also fails sleep mode... just as unstable it seems as all the 6 kernels are... sticking with 5.15.0-105 as it will at least go into and out of sleep/suspend - which 6.9 kernel worked for you?

Found this on bugzilla and it matched my kernel log. Mostly Dell Notebooks like mine seem to be affected. Looks like they changed something concerning hibernation on the kernel 6.8.0 that is used in Ubuntu 24.04.01 (and my Xubuntu as well). People tried newer and older kernels, there, some worked, on some Dells id didn't, so I choosed to blacklist the intel_hid kernel module since I can do without some special intel hotkeys that I never used the years bevor (solution in comment 33). Added blacklist intel_hid to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. No I can hibernate again.
